# Python - Most efficient means of testing if a list of time intervals contains clashes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list of time intervals, something like this:

```
[ [1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [1,1.5], [1.5,2.5] ]
```

I want to be able to test if the list contains any clashes.

For my purposes, I do not consider it to be a clash if one event ends at the exact same time as another starts. In the case above the following entries would be considered to clash:

```
[1,2] and [1,2]
[1,2] and [1,1.5]
[1,2] and [1.5,2.5]
```

I don't actually need to know which entries in the list clash, just if a clash exists or not.

I am a bit unsure what the most efficient means of making this determination in python.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

edit: in another case, [1, 5] and [2, 3] would also be considered to clash

Comment: Do `[1, 5]` and `[2, 3]` clash?

Comment: [1, 5] and [2, 3] would be considered to clash

Comment: So you're looking for overlaps?

Comment: that is correct - I am looking for overlaps

Comment: Have a look at ["Range overlap in two compares"](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201310/range_overlap_in_two_compares.html), the gist of it is that ranges do not overlap, if they're entirely less or greater than the other. In your case you then just have to handle the "`end_of_1 == start_of_2`" and vice versa cases too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def clash(a,b):
    if a == True or b == True:
        return True

    if b[0] >= a[0] and a[-1] >b[0]:
        return True
    return b

def test_clashes(intervals):
    intervals = sorted(intervals)
    if not reduce(clash,intervals) == True:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

You declare your intervals:

```
intervals = [ [1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [1,1.5], [1.5,2.5] ]
```

and you call the function in this way:

```
test_clashes(intervals)
```

The output is true if any time range overlaps with another.

How it works:

`sorted` orders our intervals in 'natural' way for python arrays: they are sorted by starting time and if starting time is the same, by ending time.

Let's assume that after sorting we have intervals `[a, b, ... , c]`.

It is given that `a[0] <= b[0] <= ... <= c[0]`.

Let's assume that `a` clashes with `c`.

That means `a[1] > c[0]`. However, that means `a[1] > c[0] >= b[0]`, so if `c` clashes with `a`, so does `b`. Thus, we only need to check consecutive intervals, instead of each interval with each interval.

Time complexity is dominated by sorting and is log(n)*n.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for overlapping ranges, but accept that start of a range may be equal to the end of the other:

```
def overlap(x, y):
    x_start, x_end = x
    y_start, y_end = y
    # return not (x_end <= y_start or y_end <= x_start)
    return x_end > y_start and y_end > x_start
```

To brute force it, just check if any 2-combination of intervals overlaps:

```
from itertools import combinations

intervals = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2], [1, 1.5], [1.5, 2.5]]
result = any(overlap(x, y) for x, y in combinations(intervals, 2))
```

As pointed out sorting the list of intervals first, or if they're sorted to begin with, allows checking consecutive intervals only:

```
sorted_intervals = sorted(intervals)
result = any(overlap(x, y) for x, y in zip(sorted_intervals,
                                           sorted_intervals[1:]))
```

Comment: I think that what you are proposing has a complexity of O(n^2) while it could be done with O(n*log(n))

Comment: @Trugis are you referring to an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or something like it?

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that you are comparing all the possible combinations of intervals, which implies that your algorithm has a n^2 complexity, while if you first sort the intervals ( n*log(n) ) and then compare only the successive intervals ( n ) the overall complexity is n*log(n)

Comment: That's why it's called "brute force".

Comment: That's also why i believe is not the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
mylist = [ [1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [1,1.5], [1.5,2.5] ]
last = 0
for i in mylist:
        if last>i[0]:
            print('Clashed!!',first,last," and ",i[0],i[1])
        first = i[0] 
        last = i[1]
```

this will check everything and print the places where the two overlaps, hope i helped, thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Modified: to handle all possible combinations rather than just adjacent entries.

First I sort the list.

Then I compare the first element with all remaining elements to the right in the list.
Then I compare the second element with all the remaining elements to the right in the list.
And so on.

If the first value of the second inner list is less than the second value of the first inner list, there is a crash.

```
LL = [[1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [1,1.5], [1.5,2.5]]
print 'original',LL
KK = sorted(LL)
print 'sorted  ',KK
for i in range(len(KK)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(KK)):
        print i,j,
        if KK[j][0] < KK[i][1]:
            print "crash"
        else:
            print "ok"
```

output:

```
original [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2], [1, 1.5], [1.5, 2.5]]
sorted   [[1, 1.5], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1.5, 2.5], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
0 1 crash
0 2 crash
0 3 ok
0 4 ok
0 5 ok
1 2 crash
1 3 crash
1 4 ok
1 5 ok
2 3 crash
2 4 ok
2 5 ok
3 4 crash
3 5 ok
4 5 ok
```